Ansible : strange jinja2 behaviour with lowercase
can anyone explain the following Jinja behaviour in Ansible?
The following code works: The task is skipped because the job_function is not in the exclusion_functions array
- name: Lowercase test
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    job_function: 'VRIJwillig'
    exclusion_functions:
      - vrijwilliger
      - maatje

  tasks:
    - name: Test for function in exclusions
      debug:
        msg: In exclusions
      when: (job_function | lower) in exclusion_functions

The following code works as well, the second task is skipped.
- name: Lowercase test
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    job_function: 'VRIJwillig'
    exclusion_functions:
      - Vrijwilliger
      - Maatje

  tasks:
    - name: Initialiseer variabelen
      set_fact:
        exclusions: "{{ exclusion_functions | lower }}"

    - name: Test for function in exclusions
      debug:
        msg: In exclusions
      when: (job_function | lower) in exclusions

But this doesn't work, the task isn't skipped:
---
- name: Lowercase test
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    job_function: 'VRIJwillig'
    exclusion_functions:
      - Vrijwilliger
      - Maatje

  tasks:
    - name: Test for function in exclusions
      debug:
        msg: In exclusions
      when: (job_function | lower) in (exclusion_functions | lower)

Why is the task not skipped in the last code snippet? job_function | lower is vrijwillig, and exclusion_functions | lower is ['vrijwilliger','maatje'], and the first one isn't in the second one.

The value of the variable exclusion_functions is a list
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ exclusion_functions }}
          {{ exclusion_functions | type_debug }}

gives
  msg: |-
    ['Vrijwilliger', 'Maatje']
    list

The filter lower converts the argument to a string
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ exclusion_functions | lower }}
          {{ exclusion_functions | lower | type_debug }}

The output looks like a list but it isn't. It's a string
  msg: |-
    ['vrijwilliger', 'maatje']
    str

This explains why the below task isn't skipped
    - name: Test for function in exclusions
      debug:
        msg: In exclusions
      when: (job_function | lower) in (exclusion_functions | lower)

The value VRIJwillig of the variable job_function is converted to lowercase vrijwillig which is in the string ['vrijwilliger', 'maatje']
The solution is to map the filter lower to each list's item
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ exclusion_functions | map('lower') }}
          {{ exclusion_functions | map('lower') | type_debug }}

shows the result is a list with items converted to lowercase
  msg: |-
    ['vrijwilliger', 'maatje']
    list

Then, as expected, the below task is skipped
    - name: Test for function in exclusions
      debug:
        msg: In exclusions
      when: (job_function | lower) in (exclusion_functions | map('lower'))



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- name: Lowercase test
  hosts: localhost

  vars:

    job_function: VRIJwillig
    exclusion_functions:
      - Vrijwilliger
      - Maatje

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ exclusion_functions }}
          {{ exclusion_functions | type_debug }}

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ exclusion_functions | lower }}
          {{ exclusion_functions | lower | type_debug }}

    - name: Test for function in exclusions
      debug:
        msg: In exclusions
      when: (job_function | lower) in (exclusion_functions | lower)

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ exclusion_functions | map('lower') }}
          {{ exclusion_functions | map('lower') | type_debug }}

    - name: Test for function in exclusions
      debug:
        msg: In exclusions
      when: (job_function | lower) in (exclusion_functions | map('lower'))



Very good explanation regarding the difference in data types, +1

Whereby I can't answer
Q: "Can anyone explain the following Jinja behaviour in Ansible?"
in order to search for a (sub-)string in a list I like to recommend to use the approach from the following minimal example playbook
---
- name: Lowercase test
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    job_function: 'VRIJwillig'
    exclusion_functions:
      - Vrijwilliger
      - Maatje

  tasks:

    - name: Initialiseer variabelen
      debug:
        var: exclusion_functions | lower

    - name: Test for function in exclusions
      debug:
        msg: In exclusions
      when: exclusions is search(job_function | lower)
      #  Initialiseer variabelen
      vars:
        exclusions: "{{ exclusion_functions | lower }}"

resulting into an output of
TASK [Initialiseer variabelen] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  exclusion_functions | lower:
  - vrijwilliger
  - maatje

TASK [Test for function in exclusions] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: In exclusions

because the search test – Does string match a regular expression has already a Parameter: ignorecase. See in example the result of
    - name: Test for function in exclusions
      debug:
        msg: In exclusions
      when: exclusions is search(job_function, ignorecase=True)
      #  Initialiseer variabelen
      vars:
        exclusions: "{{ exclusion_functions }}"


If looking for an exact match of list elements use contains test – does the list contain this element

Checks the supplied element against the input list to see if it exists within it.

- name: Test for function in exclusions
      debug:
        msg: In exclusions
      when: exclusions is contains(job_function | lower)
      #  Initialiseer variabelen
      vars:
        exclusions: "{{ exclusion_functions | lower }}"

resulting into a SKIPPED task.
PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1

Or use the already given answer.

But even in this case, the task should be skipped: vrijwillig is NOT in exclusion_functions | lower

Ah, I see, you are looking for an exact match. That would be the contains test. I'll provide an update.
